# WCF Error: The identity check failed for the outgoing message

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client

i am trying to consuming wcf web service and got error

The identity check failed for the outgoing message. The expected identity is 'identity(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/right/possessproperty: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/spn)' for the 'http://localhost/SCVMMService/VirtualMachineManagementService.svc' target endpoint.

for consuming webservice i am using code :

```
Client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "testlab.ourcp.com";
  Client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
  Client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "M!ndMasT23";
  Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "administrator";
  Client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "M!ndMasT23";        
  Client.Open();
```

WebConfig:

```
<bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IVirtualMachineManagementService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/SCVMMService/VirtualMachineManagementService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IVirtualMachineManagementService" contract="ServiceReference1.IVirtualMachineManagementService" name="WSHttpBinding_IVirtualMachineManagementService">
                <identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value="DDC-SC-VMM02.testlab.ourcp.com\Administrator"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
```

and in webService config file for identity use:

```
    <dns value="localhost"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the WCF service you're trying to access configured to use [Service Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733130.aspx)? If not, remove the entire `identity` element from the `endpoint` element because it's only used with the Service Indentity feature.

Comment: i have changed 
<identity>
     <dns value="DDC-SC-VMM02.testlab.ourcp.com" />
    </identity>
now above Error has been resolved now i am getting New Error :

Cannot connect to SCVMM server. Exception: Microsoft.Hosting.Management.HostingManagementException - Message: Cannot connect to SCVMM server.You cannot contact the Virtual Machine Manager server. The credentials provided have insufficient privileges on localhost. Ensure that your account has access to the Virtual Machine Manager server localhost, and then try the operation again.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that issue. I've never seen that exception before in WCF.